# IE 8 - text are not aligned with table rows

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

So I have this problem that only happens in IE8 where the text on the cells are not aligh with the table rows. See image below.

[image]

The HTML and CSS is as follows:

```css
.HLTable{
 background-color: #FFFFFF; /*FFFFFF; */
}
.HLTableHD
{
 font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:13px;
 font-style:normal;
 FONT-WEIGHT: bold; 
 text-decoration:none;
 background : #f9ac4f;
 border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding-bottom : 1px;
 padding-left : 1px;
 padding-right : 1px;
 padding-top : 1px;
 text-align : center;
 height:30px;
}

.HLTableRows{
 font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:12px;
 font-style:normal;
 FONT-WEIGHT: normal;
 text-decoration:none;
 background : #F6f6f6; /*FF9900*/
 BORDER-RIGHT: 0px solid;
 BORDER-TOP: 0px solid;
 BORDER-LEFT: 0px solid;
 BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px solid;
 color:#2b2b2b;
 padding-bottom : 1px;
 padding-left : 1px;
 padding-right : 1px;
 padding-top : 1px;
 text-align : center;
 height:25px;
}

.tablePag{
 background-color: #f9f9f9; 
    padding-bottom : 1px;
 padding-left : 1px;
 padding-right : 1px;
 padding-top : 1px;
    vertical-align  : middle;
}

.tableClean{
 background-color: transparent;
 padding-bottom : 0px;
 padding-left : 0px;
 padding-right : 0px;
 padding-top : 0px;  
 BORDER-RIGHT: 0px solid;
 BORDER-TOP: 0px solid;
 BORDER-LEFT: 0px solid;
 BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px solid;
 font-size:7px;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" name="hl_000_200_100" id="hl_000_200_100" class="HLTable" style="">
  <thead>
    <tr height="19" class="HLTableHD">
      <td class="HLTableHD">ID Contencioso</td>
      <td class="HLTableHD">Nº Processo Judicial</td>
      <td class="HLTableHD">ID</td>
      <td class="HLTableHD">Empresa</td>
      <td class="HLTableHD">Nome Cliente</td>
      <td class="HLTableHD">NIF</td>
      <td class="HLTableHD" title="Data de criação do plano no sistema">Data Criação</td>
      <td class="HLTableHD">Data Início</td>
      <td class="HLTableHD" title="Data em que o plano passa para o estado Fechado">Data Fecho</td>
      <td class="HLTableHD" title="Soma total de todas as parcelas do plano">Valor Plano</td>
      <td class="HLTableHD">Criar Plano</td>
      <td class="HLTableHD" title="Detalhe das prestações do plano">Plano Prestações</td>
      <td class="HLTableHD">Custas Associadas</td>
      <td class="HLTableHD">Custos Associados</td>
      <td class="HLTableHD">Facturas Associadas</td>
      <td class="HLTableHD">Estado</td>
      <td class="HLTableHD">Responsável</td>
      <td class="HLTableHD" title="Acordo Formal">Acordo</td>
      <td class="HLTableHD">Incumprimento</td>
      <td class="HLTableHD">Pagamento por Conta</td>
      <td class="transparente"></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="transparent">
    <tr name="hlt_000_200_100_100__1" id="hlt_000_200_100_100__1" height="19" class="HLTableRows">
      <td class="HLTableRows">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="tableClean">
                <a name="LinkID" id="LinkID" href="someLink" target="frameEsq" class="href">1.36273720_2</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td class="HLTableRows"></td>
      <td class="HLTableRows">1663244</td>
      <td class="HLTableRows">Clix</td>
      <td class="HLTableRows">MANUEL JOSE CARDOGOS PALMA</td>
      <td class="HLTableRows">163680736</td>
      <td class="HLTableRows">19/08/2014</td>
      <td class="HLTableRows">05/09/2014</td>
      <td class="HLTableRows"></td>
      <td class="HLTableRows">180,72</td>
      <td class="HLTableRows">
        <a name="lnkCriarP" id="lnkCriarP" href="somelink" target="work" class="transparent">
          <img name="imgCriarP" id="imgCriarP" title="Retoma Plano Pagamento Simulado" border="0" src="SomePic">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="HLTableRows">
        <a name="lnkEditar" id="lnkEditar" onclick="some JS" href="javascript: return false;" class="transparent">
          <img name="imgEditar" id="imgEditar" title="Visualizar Plano de Prestações" border="0" src="SomeLink">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="HLTableRows">
        <a name="lnkCustasAssoc" id="lnkCustasAssoc" onclick="some JS" href="javascript: return false;" class="transparent">
          <img name="imgFacturasAssoc" id="imgFacturasAssoc" title="Lista de Custas Associadas ao Plano Pagamento" border="0" src="SomePic">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="HLTableRows">
        <a name="lnkCustosAssoc" id="lnkCustosAssoc" onclick="Some JS" href="javascript: return false;" class="transparent">
          <img name="imgFacturasAssoc" id="imgFacturasAssoc" title="Lista de Custos Associados ao Plano Pagamento" border="0" src="SomePIC">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="HLTableRows">Em simulação</td>
      <td class="HLTableRows">Hélder Fernando Silva</td>
      <td class="HLTableRows">Não</td>
      <td class="HLTableRows">Não</td>
      <td class="HLTableRows">Não</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <table>
```

Please keep in mind that this is a very old site and is all based on tables generated by XSLT.

Can anyone help me out with this? I'm not really a CSS expert and I am completely lost on what to do to fix this.

Comment: what about instead `height:25px`, having like `height:35px`?

Comment: Can't reproduce with your HTML

Comment: Well it happens when the name on the 5th column is really big.

Comment: Well I changed the height as sugested and everything did align better but if there is a name that's bigger, the problem still exists.

Comment: Instead of setting the 'height' property, use the 'min-height' property. This will make it so your rows will grow if the content is larger.